# Is there any way to generate Scala code from a .java file

Tags: java, scala, translation, code-translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automated Java to Scala source code conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484064/automated-java-to-scala-source-code-conversion)

Since the Scala language has all features of Java, theoretically it should be possible to generate a Scala code translated from java source code files. Is there any tool to do that translation?

For example, the following code in Java:

```
public class MyClass {

    String hello;

    public MyClass(String hello){
        this.hello = hello;           
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Sysout.println(hello);
    }
}
```

could be translated automatically to:

```
class MyClass(hello: String) {

  def doSomething() {
    println(hello);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've voted to close, but it's worth noting for the search engines that there are a handful of features of Java that Scala does not support and which are not amenable to automatic translation to Scala. These include.

- "break", "continue" and labelled statements
- some of the trickier "switch" statement semantics, including
  fallthrough
- annotations with runtime visibility
- Java-compatible enums
- The "strictfp" annotation (before Scala 2.9)
- Precise floating-point literals.